# Existence of $2$ points of same colour and $1$ distance apart, in a circle of radius more than $\frac{1}{2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math

> In a circle of radius $r> \frac{1}{2}$, every point in the interior of the circle is coloured with one of two colors red and blue. Can you always find $2$ points that are of the same colours and $1$ distance apart?

---

**Approach:** I tried some constructions. My approach was dividing the circumference into $2n$ equally spaced points and "shrink" them towards the center just a bit to create a $2n$-gon $A_1A_2A_3...A_{2n}$ whose vertices lie inside the circle. Now $A_1A_{n+1}$ passes through the center of the circle. While shrinking the points inside, we shall shrink in such a way that $A_1A_{n+1}$ is still larger than $1$. Now take another point $A_k$. Hence, $\triangle A_1A_{n+1}A_k$ is a right triangle with the right angle at $A_k$. One pair of these points must be of the same colour. Now I'm stuck here. Please **only** provide **hints**, not full solutions. Thanks.

Comment: If $r\geq\sqrt3/3,$ you can find an equilateral triangle with side $1,$ so you definitely this property then. The hard case is the smaller $r.$

Comment: Yes. This is the smaller case.

Comment: Can we use roots of unity here (as we have a regular polygon, so we might imagine it on the complex plane with $2n$th root of unity?

Comment: The only points that matter are the annulus of points distance $d$ from the center, with $1-r\leq d\leq r$ . The other points aren't distance $1$ from any points in the circle.

Comment: Hint: Draw a star without lifting your pen. This gets us all r > sin(18)/sin(36). How can we continue from here?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews What do you mean by annulus of points?

Comment: Time to learn a word. You have google or some other search engine available?

Comment: @Rafi r is the radius right? What do you mean by $r> sin(18)/sin(36)$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I did Google it before commenting. Search engine said "
a plane figure consisting of the area between a pair of concentric circles." What does it mean in lighg of your comment.

Comment: I mean that if r > sin(18)/sin(36) ≈ 0.526, then we can draw a regular (pentagonal) star in our circle whose "side" has length 1 (this is *not* the side length of the regular pentagon who shares its vertices!). Do you see how this produces for us the desired pair of points? If you want, I can post a solution...

Comment: @Rafi ok give me sometime to think about it. Thanks, i think i should be able to carry it from here.

Comment: @Rafi but that's for r>0.526 right? Which is not 1/2. So it won't work for all r>1/2?

Comment: No, but you can generalize the idea in a natural way to get r > k for k anything > 1/2.

Comment: @Rafi ok. So we shall create a regular 5 pointed star in the circle. But, here i have a doubt. The largest possible length of any line segment is the diameter which is >1. So how do we show that the star would have a side equal to 1? For any such r>1/2? Ok maybe you should post your solution, I shall clear my doubt through the whole solution

Comment: Posted below. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the circle in question as $\Omega:=\left\{z\in\mathbb{C}\text{ s.t. }\left|z\right|\leq r\right\}$ (i.e., embed it in the complex plane in the obvious way), choose $n$ sufficiently large that $$\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2\left(2n+1\right)}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2n+1}\right)}\leq r$$ (this exists as the expression tends to $\frac{1}{2}$ as $n\to\infty$), and consider the sequence of $2n+1$ points in $\Omega$ $$\left(p_{k}:=\frac{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2\left(2n+1\right)}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{2n+1}\right)}e^{\frac{2\pi i}{2n+1}nk}\in\Omega\right)_{k=0,\dots,2n}.$$ It's readily seen that $\left|p_{k+1}-p_{k}\right|=1$ (with $p_{2n+1}:=p_{0}$), so by the familiar argument one of the pairs $(p_{k},p_{k+1})$ must be monochromatic of mutual distance $1$, as desired.

Comment: Do you mean to have an $i$ in the argument of your $\sin$ functions?  And I think you mean $p_{2n+1}=p_0$.

Comment: No and yes; fixed.

Comment: Welcome to the $4$-digit club.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z_n=e^{2n\pi i/(2n+1)}.$

Show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n=-1,$ and hence $\lim |1-z_n|=2.$

So, since $r>\frac12,$ $\frac1r<2.$ Let $n$ be a value such that $|1-z_n|>\frac1r.$

Now consider the points:

$$w_k=\frac{z_n^{k}}{|1-z_n|},k=0,1,\dots,2n+1$$

We have $|w_k|=\frac{1}{|1-z_n|}<r,$ so the $w_k$ are in our circle. We also have $w_{2n+1}=w_{0}.$

Finally, we have $$|w_{k}-w_{k+1}|=|z_n|^k\frac{|1-z_n|}{|1-z_n|}=1.$$

So we have a loop of an odd number of points inside our circle, each neighboring pair of which is distance $1.$

---

This is essentially a $(2n+1)$-pointed star. We just need to pick $n$ large enough that the circle necessary for a $(2n+1)$-pointed star with sides of length $1$ fits inside the circle of radius $r.$